# Perform SUM, and CASE WHEN

Tags: sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I get this error:

> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I would like to:

1. Select all columns from table `b`
2. When there is the same `numberID` I would like to perform `SUM` and return one row with result
3. Also, if there is just one `numberID` I would like to return result
4. I would like to create one more column Case with the following output “Percentage is…” (value from column Percentage)

Code so far:

```
select distinct 
   b.*, 
   case 
      when b.NumberID = b.NumberID then SUM(d.Percentage) 
   end as Percentage, 
   NULL as LName, 
   NULL as FName, 
   'Percentage is' + convert(VARCHAR(20), 
                             CASE WHEN b. NumberID = b.NumberID 
                                    THEN SUM(d.Percentage) END) as Case

from 
    Accounting b
join (
     select b.* 
     from Accounting b

    join (
        select number
             , MAX(id) id 
        from Accounting 
        where Date < '2012-12-01'
        group by number
        ) a 
    on b.number = a.number
         and b.Id = a.id
    ) b2 
on b.number = b2.number 
where b.Date > '2012-12-01'
group by b.NumberID
```

Comment: you are using an aggregate function without a `group by` clause?

Comment: I would be very careful to re-use the same table alias `b` for various table in single statement. Use separate aliases - also, I'd recommend something **more meaningful** - like `a` or `Acc` for the `Accounting` table...

Comment: I changed for group by b.NumberID. Still doesn't work

Comment: Where is `d.Percentage` coming from? I don't see a table with the alias of `d`.  Should that be `b.Percentage`?

Comment: you need to have all the fields in B.* included in either the group by or an aggregate...

Comment: d.Percentage? You don't have a table alias d? What are you actually trying to achieve with your query?

Comment: whats the structure of your accounting table?

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct in the `SELECT` under join as well.

```
//etc.
join 
(
select DISTINCT b.* from 
  Accounting b
//etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You case syntax is incorrect. Check the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).
It should go like this:

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value
```

so in your case (jeje)

```
select distinct b.*, 
case b.NumberID when  b.NumberID then ...
```

which is strange indeed. b.NumberID is always b.NumberID :o

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.NumberID, SUM(b.Percentage) AS Percentage, 
(
  SELECT MAX(s.id)
  FROM Accounting s
  WHERE s.Date < '2012-12-01' AND s.number = b.number
) AS MaxID
FROM Accounting b
WHERE b.Date > '2012-12-01'
GROUP BY b.NumberID
```

Comment: **@Tom Jerry**, will my answer run without error and does it get you close to what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

You need all of the columns in your select statement included in the Group By clause. Let's say I have a table of ice cream favors and people that ordered them. I have data that says

- Joe ordered chocolate
- Katie ordered Strawberry
- Mary ordered chocolate

If I tell sql to group by the ice cream flavor, I am telling it that I only want one row to be returned for that flavor. By including the customer's name in my select, I am asking sql who ordered each of the flavors. How can I show (in one row) who ordered chocolate? In order to ask sql for the information that I want, I need a row for each customer and each ice cream flavor (Maybe Mary ordered strawberry yesterday). So, I need to group by both customer and ice cream flavor.

Agregate functions don't need to be in the group by clause because you are asking sql a specific question regarding the data. Maybe I want to know the person whose name comes first alphabetically. Then, I could select the max(customer) and group by just the ice cream flavor.

```
Select b.id, b.number, b.firmname, b.date, sum(...)
From 
Group by b.id, b.number, b.firmname, b.date
```

Notes:

- You can still use the b.* syntax, as long as you name all the columns
  in your group by
- The distinct keyword is no longer necessary in your select, since
  group by does essentially the same thing